# Selenium get_attribute returns none

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
url="https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/poland/ekstraklasa/lks-lodz-lechia-gdansk/fgQY4hAD/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1.5)

trs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@id='odds-content']/div/div/table/tbody/*")
```

Now im trying to get the "data-opening-odds" class inside that xpath. The xpath corresponds to the green line on the image and i want to scrape the red line.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGphj.png)

Im trying `trs[0].get_attribute("data-opening-odd")` but that returns a None type

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are after the `td` "data-opening-odd" attribute, but the xpath matches `tr`s. The below xpath will match only `td`s having that attribute:

```
tds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr/td[@data-opening-odd]")
```

Or, same thing using css selector:

```
tds = driver.find_elements_by_css_selctor("table#sortable-1 > tbody > tr > td[data-opening-odd]")
```

Comment: Im trying that solution but im getting the "data-odd" instead the "data-opening-odds" and i don't know why happens this.

Comment: How are you accessing the attribute value?

Comment: In the code i've posted im getting "data-odd" so my idea is one time im in the right row of the table access to "data-opening-odd" value starting from the xpath i ve writed. Now i ve just copied and paste the code you provide me but i dont know how im getting "data-odd" value of all rows

Comment: I get that. I am asking you to show the exact code you run for that, because when I print the results I get the correct "data-opening-odds" and not "data-odd".

Comment: just that `browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/poland/ekstraklasa/lks-lodz-lechia-gdansk/fgQY4hAD/"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1.5)
#-----------------------1x2----------------<--


tds = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr/td[@data-opening-odd]")`  Then i made a loop to iterate all the tds and show me the data-odd

Comment: "Then i made a loop to iterate all the tds and show me the data-odd" -  So how do you do that? Can't help unless you are specific and show code...

Comment: Just `for i in tds: print(i.text)`

Comment: There you go :) That's the problem. Do a `print(i.get_attribute("data-opening-odd")` instead.